# access final value of array out of loop scope

Tags: perl

How can i access the **@missing** array values out of the scope when the loop is complete ?

I have tried to declare it out of the scope but when i print out of the scope i get no values.
**Here is my code :**

```
my $last= $order[0];
for my $cur ( @order[1..$#order] ) {
   .
   .
   .
   my @missing = grep { ! $b{$_} } @aa;
   print Dumper @missing;
   $last = $cur; 
}
```

Comment: You are not attempting to access the `@missing` array outside of the loop. Do you want to save all the different elements of `@missing` for each iteration?

Comment: Also, your error is unrelated to anything in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not trying to access the `@missing` array in your code, so I am a little confused as to what you mean, exactly. But I *assume* that what you want is to store the different elements from `@missing` for each iteration. So, do that.

```
my @all_missing;
for .... {
    ...
    my @missing = grep { ! $b{$_} } @aa;
    push @all_missing, \@missing;            # store ref to array
}

# all the "missing" elements are now stored in the two-dimensional array
# @all_missing
```

Because you use a lexical variable `@missing`, you can store a reference to it directly. Each iteration it will go out of scope and be initialized to a new memory address.

Comment: this answers my question perfectly ! after that i made the array flat since i don't need 2D. Thanks :)

Comment: Oh, is that what the `flat` subroutine does? If you don't want a 2D array, just take the array, instead of a reference: `push @all, @missing`

Comment: Yes :) It's a routine from CPAN List::Flatten; Thank you TLP.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is a loop my variable, which has scope only in the for loop.

Declare @missing before the loop if you want to access it in the scope enclosing the loop.

```
my $last= $order[0];
my @missing = ();
for my $cur ( @order[1..$#order] ) {
   my @aa= flat $last;
   my @bb= flat $cur;
   my %b = map { $_ => 1 } @bb;
   @missing = ();  # reset from last use
   @missing = grep { ! $b{$_} } @aa;
   print Dumper @missing;
   $last = $cur; 
}   

print STDOUT "Final missing: ",@missing;
```

Comment: This could be very strange, i did that and i even just added the "missing" reset as you did. But the final print missing is still empty. When i run the script it just ends after a while.

Comment: Make sure you no longer have a `my @missing` inside the for loop... You could print Dumper instead of print STDOUT.... Also, try printing @order before the loop, if @order is empty the loop does nothing.

Comment: thank you for your assistance. The solution provided by TLP worked :) you got my vote :)